# resolve.alias not working webpack 2

Tags: node.js, webpack, config, webpack-2

im using webpack (2.6.1) and im trying to use resolve.alias but tried lot of things but still not working.

I have some import like this:

```
import {helper} from 'helper'
```

where helper is from a node module from a custom node module path, so i tried:

```
alias: {
      helper: path.resolve(".", 'node_modules',  "core.commons.helper", "helper")
}
```

Im using "." cause i want resolve with the node modules from the path where i run webpack.

But still not working, i tried also with:

```
modules: [
  path.resolve(".", 'node_modules'),
  'node_modules'
],
```

but still not working neither.

Any help would be great.

EDIT:

I have repo A for testing where i have karma, webpack and babel config. I run karma with webpack as preprocessor with files from repo B and i'm trying to load node modules from repo A instead from repo B.

I tried with resolve.modules but still not finding the module.

Repo A and B are at the same level.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? In particular, could you post the errors you are getting? Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: @IsiahMeadows edited thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `resolve.modules`, e.g., assuming your Webpack config is under repoA:

```js
resolve: {
    modules: [ path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules') ]
}
```